# Any downsides of moving from GDI+ to OpenGL?

Tags: winapi, opengl, graphics, gdi+

I recently moved the rendering part of a program of mine from GDI+ to OpenGL.

Now I'm wondering: are there any *downsides* to doing so?

For example, are there any versions of Windows (XP or later) that support GDI+ but not OpenGL?
Or, for example, is it possible for a lack of drivers (or poor drivers), or a lack of a graphics card, etc. to make OpenGL rendering impossible on a system on which GDI+ works fine?

(I understand the OpenGL might need to resort to software rendering on less capable systems, but aside from slowness, I'm wondering if it would ever simply *not work* correctly in a situation in which GDI+ would.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the OpenGL version/profile you're using. Up to, inclusing Windows XP OpenGL-1.1 is available by default without additional drivers. Since Windows Vista the minimum available OpenGL version is OpenGL-1.4.

However if you need anything more than that, you're relying on the user installing the drivers that come from the GPU vendor; the drivers installed by default in a standard Windows installation don't cover OpenGL (for not perfectly sane reasons).

Programs and libraries that strongly depend on OpenGL-ES have resorted to incorporate fallbacks like [ANGLE](https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/).

Comment: Ah I see. So if I'm using nothing after OpenGL-1.1 then there is no reason I should be worried about moving away from GDI+, correct?

Comment: I just thought of a problem myself: if someday I need to add text rendering, it will be extremely difficult in OpenGL.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes text rendering is still a very big issue with OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

There are some idiosyncrasies, as for example: you cannot create a transparent `OpenGL` window, if transparency is disabled (which means, not at all, under `XP`). Otherwise, as datenwolf notes, there's `ANGLE`, but even that does not always work. Another option might be `mesa3d` compiled for the windows target, with software rendering enabled. This option might be the safest one and faster than the software `OpenGL` 1.1 implementation from Microsoft.